# How to separate a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, date-formatting

How can I separate a sequence of numbers of a series in a dataframe like `20191110` into `2019-11-10` using python and pandas?

It should be a Date format

I tried: `df = pd.to_datetime(df.date)`

But it gave me a complete wrong date.
It turned `20191028` into: `1970-01-01 00:00:00.020191028`

Comment: You want to insert hyphens in two positions in your string, or is there something more complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('20191110', "%Y%m%d").date()

#output
datetime.date(2019, 11, 10)
```

For a series you can do:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # Data type of the series will become object(string)
```

OR

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A']).dt.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: I need to change a whole Series in my Dataframe

Comment: I have added `astype('datetime64[ns]')` incase you need `datetime64[ns]`